# how to write query in mongo db based on string date

Tags: mongodb

Order Collection

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    OrderStatus: "Shipped",
    "PurchaseDate" : "2018-01-29T20:59:55Z",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    OrderStatus: "Shipped",
    "PurchaseDate" : "2018-01-30T20:59:55Z",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    OrderStatus: "Shipped",
    "PurchaseDate" : "2018-01-30T20:59:55Z",
  }
];
```

Order Detail Collection

```
[
  {
    orderid: 1,
    "QuantityShipped" : "1",
    "Amount" : "10",
  },
  {
    orderid: 2,
    "QuantityShipped" : "2",
    "Amount" : "20",
  },
  {
    orderid: 3,
    "QuantityShipped" : "1",
    "Amount" : "30",
  },
{
    orderid: 3,
    "QuantityShipped" : "1",
    "Amount" : "30",
  }

];
```

Result:

```
{
  sales: 80,
  count: 3
}
```

This is result will get when based on purchase date `2018-01-30T20:59:55Z`.
First we need to subtract 7 hours from purchase date then do filter. lets say
if i subtract 7 hours `2018-01-30T20:59:55Z` than may or may be not date will change. then we have to
filter based on date.

Sales will calculate based on sum of order detail collection.
Count will calculated based on orderdetail count.

how to write query in mongo db.

Comment: When you filter on date after subtraction, what does that filter look like... is it exact match on date or range and is the date filter coming as `string` or `date` and what format. Is it something like this: `$match:{PurchaseDate: filterDate}`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$dateFromString` it converts a date/time string to a date object, and then you can simply put groupby query and get this result

follow this link https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/

Comment: Can you write query. or how can we subtract 7 hours from date then where condtion should be match.